# How to create new record from web service in ADF?

Tags: web-services, soap, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have created a class and published it as web service. I have created a web method like this:

```
    public void addNewRow(MyObject cob) {
    MyAppModule myAppModule = new MyAppModule();
    try {
        ViewObjectImpl vo = myAppModule.getMyVewObject1();
    ================> vo object is now null
        Row r = vo.createRow();
        r.setAttribute("Param1", cob.getParam1());
        r.setAttribute("Param2", cob.getParam2());
        vo.executeQuery();
        getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As I have written in code, myAppModule.getMyVewObject1() returns a null object. I do not understand why! As far as I know AppModule has to initialize the object by itself when I call "getMyVewObject1()" but maybe I am wrong, or maybe this is not the way it should be for web methods. Has anyone ever faced this issue? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_52/jdtut_11r2_52_6.html ? I think problem is in your AppModule initialization.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, you think right. But this tutorial does not explain how to initialize the appmodule from a webservice. Can you help with a small hint? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check nice tutorial: [Building and Using Web Services with JDeveloper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_52/jdtut_11r2_52_1.html)
It gives you general idea about how you should build your webservices with ADF.

Another approach is when you need to call existing Application Module from some bean that doesn't have needed environment (servlet, etc), then you can initialize it like this:

```
String appModuleName = "org.my.package.name.model.AppModule";
String appModuleConfig = "AppModuleLocal";
ApplicationModule am = Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(appModuleName, appModuleConfig);
```

Don't forget to release it:

```
Configuration.releaseRootApplicationModule(am, true);
```

And [why you shouldn't really do it like this.](https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/when_to_use_createrootapplicationmodule_in_oracle_adf)
[And even more...](http://radio-weblogs.com/0118231/2009/08/20.html)

Better aproach is to get access to binding layer and do call from there.
[Here is a nice article.](http://tompeez.wordpress.com/tag/binding-layer/)

Comment: I notice the "nice article" still uses the Configuration.createRoot... - I think Frank's article on not using it is for when you are calling ADF BC from ADF Faces - via the supplied binding layer. However, I think in Albano's example, he does not have a binding layer. I'll check with Frank and post a follow up.

Comment: @Joe That article describes both approaches. Creating new AppModule from config and another - accessing it through binding layer. You can use both, just best practices suggest to prefer binding layer method.

Answer (score 1):

Per Our PM : If you don't use it in the context of an ADF application then the following code should be used (sample code is from a project I am involved in). Note the release of the AM at the end of the request

@WebService(serviceName = "LightViewerSoapService")
public class LightViewerSoapService {

```
private final String amDef = " oracle.demo.lightbox.model.viewer.soap.services.LightBoxViewerService";
private final String config = "LightBoxViewerServiceLocal";

LightBoxViewerServiceImpl service;

public LightViewerSoapService() {
    super();
}


@WebMethod
public List<Presentations> getAllUserPresentations(@WebParam(name = "userId")       Long userId){

  ArrayList<Presentations> al = new ArrayList<Presentations>();

  service =   (LightBoxViewerServiceImpl)getApplicationModule(amDef,config);
  ViewObject vo = service.findViewObject("UserOwnedPresentations");

  VariableValueManager vm = vo.ensureVariableManager();
  vm.setVariableValue("userIdVariable", userId.toString());

  vo.applyViewCriteria(vo.getViewCriteriaManager().getViewCriteria("byUserIdViewCriteria"));
  Row rw = vo.first();

    if(rw != null){

        Presentations p = createPresentationFromRow(rw);           
        al.add(p);

        while(vo.hasNext()){
            rw = vo.next();
            p = createPresentationFromRow(rw);           
            al.add(p);
        }      
    }

    releaseAm((ApplicationModule)service);
    return al;
  }
```

Have a look here too:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDBd3JuroMQ

Comment: Thanks, releaseAm((ApplicationModule)service) is a method of LightBoxViewerServiceImpl ? I did what Nagh wrote and it works now, this solution seems nice but I don't know if I have to import other libraries..